# I cannot find question, is it deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question

there was a question about problem with industrial partner in Marie Curie program,

I tried search menu, but nothing came out both times.

Can anyone help me find? thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean this question: [Should I quit if I'm having problems with the Marie Curie industry partner?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/111002/should-i-quit-if-im-having-problems-with-the-marie-curie-industry-partner)

I found it via google using the search term *[industrial partner in Marie Curie program stack exchange](http://www.google.co.th/search?q=industrial%20partner%20in%20Marie%20Curie%20program%20stack%20exchange)*.

As a rule, google indexes posts on StackExchange rather quickly, so if you can't find it using the internal search tool, google often helps.